# increasing variable value only one in the render ( ) libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, render

I have a variable that I have to incremente when performing the collision , I put the control in the render ( ) method and of course , the render is super fast. So, increased it by much more.

It does not quite understand how to do this despite being one of only increase in render, someone recommend me an idea ?

```
render()
{
   ..
    if(!actorsRectangles.isEmpty() && !actorsImages.isEmpty()){
            for(int i = 0; i < actorsRectangles.size(); i++) {
                actorsRectangles.get(i).setX(actorsImages.get(i).getX());
                actorsRectangles.get(i).setY(actorsImages.get(i).getY());
                if (lineaDiCollisione.overlaps(actorsRectangles.get(i))) {
                    if(lineCollisionBoolean){
                        pointsLabel.setText("collision red rectangle " + playerData.contatoreOstacoli);
                    }
                    lineCollisionBoolean = false;

                }
                else{
                    lineCollisionBoolean = true;
                }
            }
        }
    ..
}
```

//preset lineCollisionBoolean at true

each time that an actor passes on lineOfCollision then you must increase the value of a.

The counter variable I'd like to be incremented only one value at a time , however as I said earlier , the make has time to verify the overlaps several times , and every time I rightly increments.

Comment: You must use a flag, increase value when collition but at same time set it to `true` after set to `false` when collision ends... not familiar with [tag:libgdx] but it's a typical programming trick ;)

Comment: I would also adopted as a solution I was hoping for something specific " donated " by the framework , I use it recently but it seems very powerful .

Comment: Thats why i didnt posted it as answer, hope you can find something more specific than a workaround, but since then, at least you can continue developing. ;)

Comment: It is so fast that I also resets the variable to true, and then I counted . You have solutions other than my own ?